# How to add DELETE method inside 'do' keyword in config/routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I can add a new DELETE method on http://localhost:3000/students by editing config/routes.rb:

```
resources :students
delete '/students',:to => 'students#destroymany'
```

Note: it is different from DELETE http://localhost:3000/students/1 because  the default DELETE supports deleting 1 student only, while I also want to support DELETE on http://localhost:3000/students/ (without specific student id)

but it has a disadvantage: I need to repeat typing 'students'. Is there any syntax that changes the routing statement to become

```
resources :students do
    xxx
end
```

but have the same effect as the beginning version? I tried:

```
resources :students do
  delete '',:to => 'students#destroymany'
end
```

but the error occurs:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/students"
```

because it adds the routing to

```
/students/:student_id
```

instead of

```
/students
```

Comment: Why adding a separate delete method? `resources :students` will give a delete route by itself. All you need to pas an `:id` to it. Unless you need it for a custom method, it is not necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is different from DELETE http://localhost:3000/students/1, because
>   the default DELETE supports deleting 1 student only, while I also want
>   to support DELETE on http://localhost:3000/students/ (without specific
>   student id)

Well add it on a [*collection*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) then

```
resources :students do
  delete '', :to => 'students#destroymany', on: :collection
end
```

This will give the below route

```
DELETE /students(.:format)  students#destroymany
```

So, you can call `/students` with `method: :delete`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead, for what you are trying to accomplish :

```
resource :students do 
  collection do 
    delete '', to: 'students#destroymany'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of singular resource. Singular resource will give you delete route without any ID

```
resource :students
```

DELETE /students students#destroy
please refer [singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)